# MS Access 2010 decode database

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a MS Access 2003 .mdb database and I would like to convert it to .accdb.

I installed MS Office 2010, removed the password and when I try to Save Database As .accdb I receive the following message:

> You are trying to convert an encoded database. Decode the database and
>   then try again.

I did not find any other options in MS Access 2010 to decode the database.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In access 2007 "Encode/Decode Database" is on the "Database Tools" ribbon tab once you open an older mdb

Comment: Agreed. Is it possible to encode/decode db in Access 2010 ?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to Decode the database before attempting your conversion.  I found the following Microsoft article about it:

[Overview of Access security (MDB)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/overview-of-access-security-mdb-HP005188226.aspx)

Here is an excerpt from it:

> The simplest method of protection is to encode the database. Encoding
>   a database compacts the database file and helps protect it from being
>   read by a word processor. Encoding a database that employs no security
>   measures has no effect, because anybody can open the database and gain
>   full access to all objects in the database. Encoding is particularly
>   useful when you transmit a database electronically, or when your store
>   it on floppy disk, tape, or compact disc.
>
> Before you can encode or decode a Microsoft Access database, you must
>   be either the owner of the database or, if the database employs
>   security measures, a member of the Admins group of the workgroup
>   information file that contains the accounts used to help protect the
>   database. You must also be able to open the database in exclusive
>   mode, which means you must have Open/Run and Open Exclusive
>   permissions.
>
> Decoding a database reverses the encoding.

Once you decode it you should be able to run the conversion.

Comment: Did you try the option under File > Info > Users and Permissions > Encode/Decode Database?

Answer (score 0):

I got that message when trying to open an Access 97 database in Access 2010. I was given the option to convert the database to Access 2010 or to open the database without full functionality. When I chose to convert the database, I got the message about it being encoded. The solution turned out be opening the database without full functionality and then saving it in Access 2000 format. After that, Access 2010 was able to open it.